# Table scrolls over fixed div when I would like it to scroll under

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a couple tables I built with angularjs plug-in, ng-grid. I have a fixed header tab on top and a fixed left panel both set just by position:fixed. Everything in the body seems to scroll under these divs just fine, except these ng-grids. This may not be a specific angularjs question, because I may have seen this before with more general tables. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you played with `z-index` yet?

Comment: Give the item you want something to be scrolled under a `z-index` of 1 in CSS because `z-index` is at default a -1.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below solution :

Give the table a `position:relative` property and then add a `z-index:1` to it. 
All the order divs which you want to be above the table should have a higher z-index value.